# Switch between EditorFor and DisplayFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial view which is setup as a table/grid showing records from a DB - I can easily get it to display my Display or Editor template for the row, but how can I switch the row from `displayFor` to `editorFor` when I click and edit or save link?

```
<div id="compQuestionListContainer">
    <div class="divQuestionItems">
        <div class="divQuestionItemsHeaderRow">
            <div class="QuestionHeader">Question Type</div>
            <div class="QuestionHeader question-name">Question Name</div>
            <div class="QuestionHeader question-required">Required</div>
            <div class="QuestionHeader question-group">Question Group</div>
            <div class="QuestionHeader">Modified By</div>
            <div class="QuestionHeader">Modified Date</div>
            <div class="QuestionHeader question-edit">Edit</div>
            <div class="QuestionHeader question-delete">Delete</div>
        </div>
        <div class="divOrderItemsBody">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CompetitionQuestionList)
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CompetitionQuestionList)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do things like this in Razor:

```
@{
   if (someCondition)
   {
      Html.EditorFor(m => m.CompetitionQuestionList);
   }
   else
   {
      Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CompetitionQuestionList);
   }
}
```

## Update

If you are trying to change from one view to another depending on user actions you will have to take another approach.

For example, you can render both in the view:

```
<div id="editor" style="display:none;">
    Html.EditorFor(m => m.CompetitionQuestionList)
</div>
<div id="display">
    Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CompetitionQuestionList)
</div>
```

And then, in your client code (assuming you load jQuery), you can do:

```
$("#editor").show();
$("#display").hide();
```

To switch from *display* to *editor*.